# php regex to extract single parameter value from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm working with a string containing parameters, separated by some special characters in PHP with preg_match

An example could be like this one, which has four parameters.

```
1stparm?#?1111?@?2ndParm?#?2222?@?3rdParm?#?3333?@?4thparm?#?444?@?
```

Each parameter name is followed by ?#?, and its value is right next to it, ending with ?@? (note: values can be strings or numbers, and even special characters)

I've probably overcomplicated my regex, which works in SOME cases, but not if I search for the last parameter in the string..

This example returns 2222 as the correct value (in group 1) for 2ndParm

```
(?:.*)2ndParm\?#\?(.*?)\?@\?(?=.)(.*)
```

but it fails if 2ndParm is the last one in the string as in the following example:

```
1stparm?#?1111?@?2ndParm?#?2222?@?
```

I'd also appreciate help in just returning one group with my result.. i havent been able to do so, but since I always get the one I'm interested in group 1, I can get it easily anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?P<key>.+?)
\Q?#?\E
(?P<value>.+?)
\Q?@?\E
```

in `verbose` mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/nZaMEs/1/).

---

The `\Q...\E` construct disables the `?` and `#` "super-powers" (no need to escape them here).

---

In `PHP` this could be

```
<?php
$string = "1stparm?#?1111?@?2ndParm?#?2222?@?3rdParm?#?3333?@?4thparm?#?444?@?";

$regex = "~(?P<key>.+?)\Q?#?\E(?P<value>.+?)\Q?@?\E~";

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match["key"] . " = " . $match["value"] . "\n";
}

?>
```

Which yields

```
1stparm = 1111
2ndParm = 2222
3rdParm = 3333
4thparm = 444
```

---

Or shorter:

```
$result = array_map(
    function($x) {return array($x["key"] => $x["value"]);}, $matches);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without regex:

```
$str ='1stparm?#?1111?@?2ndParm?#?2222?@?3rdParm?#?3333?@?4thparm?#?444?@?';

$keyval = explode('?@?', trim($str, '?@'));

$result = [];

foreach($keyval as $item) {
    [$key, $result[$key]] = explode('?#?', $item);
}

print_r($result);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/gMVer)

Comment: Nice answer - ++.

Comment: agreed. nice and short... I became obsessed with regex, and was too focused to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a regex for everything, and you should have a serious talk with whoever invented this horrid format about the fact that JSON, YAML, TOML, XML, etc exist.

```
function bizarre_unserialize($in) {
    $tmp = explode('?@?', $in);
    $tmp = array_filter($tmp); // remove empty
    $tmp = array_map(
        function($a) { return explode('?#?', $a); },
        $tmp
    );
    // rearrange to key-value
    return array_combine(array_column($tmp, 0), array_column($tmp, 1));
}

$input = '1stparm?#?1111?@?2ndParm?#?2222?@?3rdParm?#?3333?@?4thparm?#?444?@?';

var_dump(
    bizarre_unserialize($input)
);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["1stparm"]=>
  string(4) "1111"
  ["2ndParm"]=>
  string(4) "2222"
  ["3rdParm"]=>
  string(4) "3333"
  ["4thparm"]=>
  string(3) "444"
}
```

Comment: the format is internally used by the scriptcase RAD. it POSTs user parameters inside a single parameter called nmgp_parms with the format shown.
A very useful solution yours too.